# Uncaught TypeError: Object #<HTMLDivElement> has no method 'getContext'

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas

Alright, so I got this JS code, and it's throwing the error: Uncaught TypeError: Object # has no method 'getContext'

Here is the code:

```
function update(){
    var ctx = $("#canvas")[0].getContext('2d');

    ctx.fillStyle = "#A68064";
    ctx.fillRect(0,0,900, 450);
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#canvas").width(900);
    $("#canvas").height(450);
    update();
    setInterval(update, 100);
});
```

Here is a JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/LDUjA/

Can someone please tell me how properly aquire the context of a canvas element? This way use to work before, and I'm on Chrome, and know it supports canvas.

Comment: `This way use to work before` I'm not sure how. [**getContext()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Canvas/Tutorial/Basic_usage) is a method on the canvas element. Check `The rendering context` section in linked documentation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to use a canvas element. You're trying to call .getContext on just a div.

Change HTML to:

```
<body>
    <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Either What Kinakuta said, or, you're calling your getContext before the page is fully loaded.